# C++ invalid order of execution for cin and cout on XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, gcc

I ran into this issue when I updated both MacOS and XCode.

As you see in the first picture, if I don't put `endl` into the second `cout` line "Enter the number" at line 11, this line is put after the `cin` statement which makes the program run inappropriately.

The `cout` is printed after accepting input from `cin`

[image: Sample C++ code]

Here is the output of the program:

[image]

However, if I put `endl` at the end of the line "Enter the number" then the code runs normally.

I already reinstalled XCode the problem is still there. It also affects my old projects which are really annoying.

This is the version of the compiler on my Macbook

```
"Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr 
--with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1

Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.38)

Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.5.0

Thread model: posix

InstalledDir:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin"
```

I really hope someone can help me solve this issue. I don't know the bug comes from XCode or the GCC.

Comment: Cout is buffered. Flush it with outputting `endl` or by manually calling `flush`

Comment: When I use that piece of code (the one in which I don't have to use endl to flush the buffer) on a different machine (a remote linux one) or on different IDE, it works.

Comment: Apparently that other compiler flushes the stream automatically.

Comment: The current version of Xcode is buggy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43116829/xcode-thread-1-signal-sigstop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::cin` and `std::cout` are **tied**, which means that extraction operations on `std::cin` first flush `std::cout`. So your code should work as you expect it to. If it doesn't, then either the standard library that your code uses does not conform to the language definition (unlikely), or there's something funky in your console window (much more likely). Try running the program from the command line.